# What is the meaning of acute apathy that makes it an oxymoron?

Tags: phrase-meaning, oxymoron

So I'm not getting why *acute apathy* is an oxymoron. I looked these up in a dictionary. *Apathy* means "lack of interest" and *acute* means "intense". But I still don't get why it's an oxymoron, and I've looked up *oxymoron* too!

Comment: If you don't care about something, how can you do so _acutely_? Really, it's as simple as that. (BTW, as a side note, you might be interested in [ell.se].)

Comment: 'Oxymoron' is used in two distinct ways: _an apparent contradiction expressed concisely (apparent meaning that when examined more closely, some sense can be made of the statement/term)_ // _a genuine contradiction in terms, which will never be reconciled_ . If we consider a continuum rather than two disjoint classes, 'acute apathy' seems to be nearer the 'contradiction in terms' (nonsense) end of the spectrum, though doubtless (a) someone will find a sense of 'acute' they think justifies the usage and (b) it will be used for effect (comic &/or emphasis), quite possibly justifiably.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think it's an oxymoron in the classic sense (like "freezing hot", or "whitish black") - *Acute apathy* is a sudden sharp, severe or intense lack of caring.

> Jim was always really invested in my travel stories, but when I regaled him with highlights of my Spanish trip he showed an acute apathy.

There are probably better ways to express the same thing - marked disinterest, sudden indifference, heightened dispassion.